# prevent user from putting 0000 in date field

Tags: 7, datetime

How can I force date validation upon input of a content type so that a user cannot type in 0000 as the year which causes an error in  Drupal 7.

Comment: need more info. what type of form is this? also, my two cents:  don't bother.  if your user wants to be an idiot and type "0000" in the year field, they'll understand when they see an error and it doesn't work.

Comment: just on the normal content edit page.

Comment: yes I know but the tester insists on making this a high defect if he puts in 0000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Field Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_validation) to check against the date, it has a sub module or feature that has date validation.

You could also do this with a hook, probably [hook node validate](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7) would be your best option for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this module to define fields as date fields:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1455576

Alternatively, you could add JS or PHP validation of expected formats to your form.